# How to display the accuracy graph on TensorBoard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, detection, tensorboard

I'm new to TensorFlow. I am currently working on a project that uses the TF Object detection API. I'm training a model with two classes on my custom images. So far I have successfully run `train.py` and `eval.py` and executed TensorBoard at the same time to see how the training processes is progressing.

Here is the image of my work:

[image]

How do I display a graph in which I can see the accuracy of the model being developed ?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by switching from the deprecated train.py and eval.py to the recent model_main.py. It interleaves evaluation schedule into the training session, so that you can evaluate the training progress of the model without manually doing so.
The flags of model_main.py are very similar to those of train.py, and you can see an example in here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-training-job